# Online schedule planner for single student lessons

Tags: time-management, educational, scheduling, planning

I haven't found any solution to a common problem:

Teacher has some time slots to teach N students (single and small group lessons).
Every student has a school schedule (= constraint)

Now, enter every students constraints and get proposals for how to assign students to time slots with minimal collisions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any other features you specifically need/want?

Comment: Yes, an online service :) Somewhat funny that it doesn't already exist or rank high in google. Maybe the problem is somewhat more complex than what I'm thinking now, with all that game theory going into how students place/move their constraints!

Comment: Do you mean to say that [none of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+scheduling) work for you???

Comment: @user416 I'm looking for a needle in a haystack, not a haystack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Course Scheduling example ([see video](https://youtu.be/4meWIhPRVn8)) of OptaPlanner (open source, java).

Comment: This looks very promising. I will need to check if it supports variable length courses but on first look it is highly configurable.

Comment: OptaPlanner does, but not all implementations do. The school timetabling quickstart and that course scheduling example presume all lessons/courses are the same length, but the conference scheduling example and the meeting scheduling example don't.